# jasmine cleanup after async error

Tags: jasmine

I am working with selenium which does a lot of async work. If any async error is thrown, Jasmine immediately exits and does not run the appropriate `afterEach`/`afterAll`. Here is a mock example that shows sync errors are handled appropriately and execution continues. An async error stops all execution.

```
var database = [];

describe('Some Feature', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('test data buildup');
        database.push({}, {}, {})
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log('test data teardown');
        database.splice(0, database.length);
    });

    afterAll(function () {
        console.log('final test data cleanup');
        database.splice(0, database.length);
    });

    it('does something', function () {
        expect(database[1]).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('handles sync errors', function () {
        throw Error('sync error');
    });

    it('breaks on async errors', function (done) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            throw Error('async error');
            done();
        }, 1000);
    });

});


Some Feature
  does something ...
    test data buildup
    test data teardown
    Passed
  handles sync errors ...
    test data buildup
    test data teardown
    Failed
    Error: sync error
  breaks on async errors ...
    test data buildup

Error: async error
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at null._onTimeout (spec.js:30:23)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

>
```

Notice there is a `test data buildup` without a `test data teardown`, and `final test data cleanup` was never called.

Is there a way to handle async errors, or a way to ensure I can cleanup test data / selenium instances after an async failure?

Comment: I ran this exact spec through Mocha today (changing `afterAll` to `after`) and it behaves as expected, continuing execution even after the async error, and it calls the cleanup method. `done` also takes an optional error in Mocha. I am likely going to abandon Jasmine in favor of the better async support of Mocha.